# Why does my AJAX script not send GET Parameters to PHP Script?

Tags: php, ajax, parameters

I have page1.php that uses AJAX to load another PHP page which creates a dynamic HTML table, based on the "name" parameter.

To get results from the table i need to send a URL parameter called "name" via a get request.
If the script didn't use ajax it should look like this:

```
table.php?name=test
```

I am trying to replicate this with 
AJAX in page1.php:

```
<script>
        function table() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "table.php",
                type: 'get',
                data: { 
                name:test , 
        },
                success: function(data)
                    $('.table').html(response);
                }
            });
        }
                table();
        setInterval(table, 5000);
    </script>
```

The table.php contains:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
echo $name ;
?>
```

If i access `table.php?name=test` in the browser i can see the table, however AJAX is not passing the parameter, i have also tried POST.

The AJAX runs every 5 seconds to create the table, is this causing an issue with the request?

Note:
I have also tried to send just the url in ajax like:

```
        url: "table.php?name=table",
```

This also does not load my table.

Edit:
The Ajax works fine without parameters, as it shows a default table with just table.php and no Url data.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Where does the response variable come from?

Comment: `test` is being passed as a variable, not as a value. If you don't have a variable `test` then this will end up with a request `table.php?name=`. If you want to pass test as a value then put it in quotes.

Comment: Try `{ name: 'test' }` and `$('.table').html(data)` and next time, check your browser's console for errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help :)

```js
function table() {
  var test = 'test'; // or some other value, eg $('#test').val();
  $.ajax(function () {
    url: 'table.php',
    method: 'GET',
    data: { name: test },
    success: function (response) { // note the argument is "response", not "data"
      $('.table').html(response);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: OP literally says _"To get results from the table i need to send a **URL parameter** called "name" via a **get request**"_. Also, what makes you think they have an `<input>` element with `id="test"`?

Comment: Also, when you use a data _string_ like `'name=' + test`, jQuery does not encode it correctly for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` transport. However, when you use the object method like OP is (ie `{ name: test }`), keys and values are encoded correctly

Comment: _jQuery does not encode it correctly for application/x-www-form-urlencoded_ oh i didn't know this sorry. i just learned something from you haha thanks anyway. so I'm doing the wrong approach :/

Comment: Well, for OP's case, your POST request is wrong. As for the rest, it's not exactly _"wrong"_, just brittle / fragile. If you don't mind, I'm going to edit your answer a little